# Oracle instant client : ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: linux, oracle, instantclient

*What i have: red hat 6 server, remote Oracle Database with TCPS connection setup, installed oracle instant client (basic, odbc, sqlplus) from rpms.*

I'm trying to set up oracle instant client to connect to a **remote database**.
While entering command :

```
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin/sqlplus /@AVAYAPDSDB
```

I get the error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sat Aug 29 12:04:39 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR: ORA-28759: failure to open file
```

Unfortunately I have no engineers nearby who can help me to resolve this problems, so I really hope on the stack's community.

Googling for some period and searching what can help me with all that I realized that tracing of the sqlplus request would be a nice starting point. 
So now the trace of it looks like this:

```
    (1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- TRACE CONFIGURATION INFORMATION FOLLOWS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] New trace stream is /tmp/ora/cli_30063.trc
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] New trace level is 16
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- TRACE CONFIGURATION INFORMATION ENDS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- PARAMETER SOURCE INFORMATION FOLLOWS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Attempted load of system pfile source /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Parameter source loaded successfully
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] 
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Attempted load of local pfile source /root/.sqlnet.ora
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Parameter source loaded successfully
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] 
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]  -> PARAMETER TABLE LOAD RESULTS FOLLOW <-
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Successful parameter table load
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]  -> PARAMETER TABLE HAS THE FOLLOWING CONTENTS <-
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = FALSE
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = SUPPORT
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SSL_VERSION = 0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS, BEQ)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY =/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/AVAYAPDSDB)))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = /tmp/ora
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133]   SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- PARAMETER SOURCE INFORMATION ENDS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- LOG CONFIGURATION INFORMATION FOLLOWS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Log stream will be "/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/sqlnet.log"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] Log stream validation not requested
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:133] --- LOG CONFIGURATION INFORMATION ENDS ---

(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nlstdipi: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nlstdipi: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nigini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nigini: Count in the NL global area is now 1
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nigini: Count in NI gbl area now: 1
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nrigbi: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nrigbni: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:134] nrigbni: Unable to get data from navigation file tnsnav.ora
       (1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] nigini: Count in NI gbl area now: 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] nigini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] niqname: Using nnfsn2a() to build connect descriptor for (possibly remote) database.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] nnfgiinit: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] nncpcin_maybe_init: default name server domain is [root]
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:135] nnfgiinit: Installing read path
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrsp: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrsp: Obtaining path parameter from names.directory_path or native_names.directory_path
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrdp: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrdp: Setting path:
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrdp: checking element TNSNAMES
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgsrdp: Path set
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfun2a: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nlolgobj: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgrne: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgrne: Going though read path adapters
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfgrne: Switching to TNSNAMES adapter
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftboot: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nlpaxini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nlpaxini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile: construction of local names file failed
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: system names file is /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftboot: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftrne: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftrne: Original name: AVAYAPDSDB
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfttran: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: --- /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora TABLE HAS THE FOLLOWING CONTENTS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: AVAYAPDSDB = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ccpdsdko)(PORT = 2484))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastd)))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: --- END /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora TABLE ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnfttran: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftrne: Using tnsnames.ora address (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ccpdsdko)(PORT = 2484))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastd))) for name AVAYAPDSDB
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:136] nnftrne: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NI global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NL global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in the NL global area is now 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in NI gbl area now: 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niqname: Using nnfsn2a() to build connect descriptor for (possibly remote) database.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfun2a: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nlolgobj: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfgrne: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfgrne: Going though read path adapters
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfgrne: Switching to TNSNAMES adapter
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnftrne: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnftrne: Original name: AVAYAPDSDB
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfttran: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: --- /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora TABLE HAS THE FOLLOWING CONTENTS ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: AVAYAPDSDB = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ccpdsdko)(PORT = 2484))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastd)))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nncpdpt_dump_ptable: --- END /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora TABLE ---
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnfttran: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnftrne: Using tnsnames.ora address (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ccpdsdko)(PORT = 2484))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastd))) for name AVAYAPDSDB
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nnftrne: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nlolfmem: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NI global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NL global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in the NL global area is now 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in NI gbl area now: 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niqname: Hst is already an NVstring.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niqname: Inserting CID.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NI global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigtrm: Count in the NL global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in the NL global area is now 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: Count in NI gbl area now: 3
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niqname: Hst is already an NVstring.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niqname: Inserting CID.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niotns: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] niotns: niotns: setting up interrupt handler...
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:137] nigsui: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nigsui: Set User Interrupt: hdl=1, prc=0x4f9596f0, ctx=0x1bb32d0.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nigsui: exit (0)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsgblini: Max no of descriptors supported is 4096
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsgblini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snldlldl: Couldn't load shared library nque
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snldlldl: Err: /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libnque11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsbitini_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsbitini_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsbitini_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snsbitini_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] niotns: Not trying to enable dead connection detection.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] niotns: Calling address: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=ccpdsdko)(PORT=2484)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orastd)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=cc-allplus.msk.vtb24.ru)(USER=root))))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nsgettrans_bystring: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nsgettrans_bystring: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nscall: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nsmal: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nsmal: 272 bytes at 0x1bca160
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nsmal: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nscall: connecting...
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] nlad_expand_hst: Expanding ccpdsdko
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:138] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] snlinGetNameInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] snlinGetNameInfo: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nlad_expand_hst: Adding IP 10.64.245.211
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nlad_expand_hst: Result: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=10.64.245.211)(PORT=2484)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orastd)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=cc-allplus.msk.vtb24.ru)(USER=root))))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nladini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nladini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nladget: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nladget: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nsmal: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nsmal: 171 bytes at 0x1bcbc50
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nsmal: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nsc2addr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nsc2addr: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=10.64.245.211)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orastd)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=cc-allplus.msk.vtb24.ru)(USER=root))))
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] ntzini: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] ntzSetupConnection: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] ntzgbhapip: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] ntzgbhapip: no value for bhapi parameter specified - using default value: "TRUE"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] ntzgbhapip: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: parameter "trace_level_server" does not exist.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:139] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:140] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:140] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: value retrieved for parameter "trace_level_client": 0.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:140] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:140] nztysgs_genseed: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: parameter "ssl.renegotiate" does not exist.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] ntzSetupConnection: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] ntzSetupConnection: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] ntzgbhapip: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] ntzgbhapip: no value for bhapi parameter specified - using default value: "TRUE"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] ntzgbhapip: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: parameter "trace_level_server" does not exist.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: value retrieved for parameter "trace_level_client": 0.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:143] nztysgs_genseed: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: parameter "ssl.renegotiate" does not exist.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] nzsuppgp_get_parameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] ntzSetupConnection: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] ntzcsgtab: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] ntzcsgtab: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] ntzini: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] nttbnd2addr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] nttbnd2addr: using host IP address: 10.64.245.211
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:146] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nsopenalloc_nsntx: nlhthput on mplx_ht_nsgbu:ctx=1bd5fe0, nsntx=1bd6610
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nsopenmplx: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nsopen: opening transport...
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntzconnect: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntzCreateConnection: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcon: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcon: toc = 1
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcnp: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcnp: creating a socket.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcnp: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: Tcp conn timeout = 60000 (ms)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: TCP Connect TO enabled. Switching to NB
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttctl: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttctl: Setting connection into non-blocking mode
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: trying to connect to socket 4.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntt2err: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntt2err: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntctst: size of NTTEST list is 1 - not calling poll
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] sntpoltst: No of conn to test 1, wait time 60
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] sntpoltst: fd 4 need 1 readiness events
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] sntpoltst: fd 4 has 1 readiness events
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] sntpoltst: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttctl: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttctl: Clearing non-blocking mode
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] snlinGetNameInfo: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] snlinGetNameInfo: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: connected on ipaddr 10.64.245.240
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcni: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcon: NT layer TCP/IP connection has been established.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcon: set TCP_NODELAY on 4
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] nttcon: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntzAllocate: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntzAllocate: allocating 304 bytes of memory.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:147] ntzAllocate: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConfigure: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgsvp: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: found value for "ssl_version" configuration parameter: "0"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConvertToNumeric: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConvertToNumeric: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgsvp: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgcpp: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: allocating 16 bytes of memory.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: found value for "ssl_cipher_suites" configuration parameter: "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgcpp: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzCreateCipherSpec: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzCreateCipherSpec: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgcap: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgcap: retrieved value "TRUE" for client authentication parameter
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgcap: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConfigure: client authentication is required.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgwrl: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgwrlFromFile: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: found value for "wallet_location" configuration parameter: "SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY =/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/AVAYAPDSDB))"
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzGetStringParameter: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: allocating 111 bytes of memory.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: allocating 63 bytes of memory.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzAllocate: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzgwrlFromFile: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzlogin: Wallet open failed with error 28759
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzlogin: returning NZ error 28759 in result structure
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzlogin: failed with error 540
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzlogin: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConfigure: failed with error 540
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:148] ntzConfigure: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] ntzCreateConnection: failed with error 540
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] ntzconnect: failed with error 540
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] ntzconnect: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nserror: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=65, ns=12560, ns2=0; nt[0]=540, nt[1]=0, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=28759, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsopen: unable to open transport
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: acquired the bit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsbfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiofrrg: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiocancel: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsvntx_dei: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsvntx_dei: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsopenfree_nsntx: nlhthdel from mplx_ht_nsgbu, ctx=1bd5fe0 nsntx=1bd6610
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiocancel: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiofrrg: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiofrrg: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsiocancel: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbittrm_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbittrm_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: acquired the bit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitts_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitcl_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] snsbitcl_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: 2760 bytes at 0x1bd6610
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: 1576 bytes at 0x1bd5fe0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsopen: error exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsclose: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsclose: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nladget: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nladget: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: 171 bytes at 0x1bcbc50
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: 272 bytes at 0x1bca160
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nsmfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nladtrm: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nladtrm: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nscall: error exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:  error from nscall
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:    ns main err code: 12560
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:    ns (2)  err code: 0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:    nt main err code: 540
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:    nt (2)  err code: 0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] nioqper:    nt OS   err code: 0
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] niomapnserror: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] niqme: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:149] niqme: reporting ORA-28759 error
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] niqme: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] niomapnserror: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] niotns: Couldn't connect, returning 28759
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] niotns: exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nigcui: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nigcui: Clr User Interrupt: hdl=1, prc=0x4f9596f0, ctx=0x1bb32d0.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nigcui: exit (0)
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] snsbittrm_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] snsbittrm_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] snsbittrm_ts: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] snsbittrm_ts: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nsbfrfl: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nsbrfr: entry
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nsbrfr: nsbfs at 0x1bcbfe0, data at 0x1bd70e0.
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nsbrfr: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nsbfrfl: normal exit
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nigtrm: Count in the NI global area is now 2
(1309189888) [29-AUG-2015 12:04:39:150] nigtrm: Count in the NL global area is now 2
```

Pleeeease! anyone! I see only that one .so file is missing. I can't find anything about the same trouble anywhere, maybe with other .so files and the recomendations were to make symlinks like so:

```
 /usr/sbin/semanage fcontext -a -t textrel_shlib_t $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libnque11.so
```

but the system write that I don't have "semanage ". Any suggestions would be so greatly appreciated!?!

[Upd 1]
my /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
AVAYAPDSDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = ccpdsdko)(PORT = 2484))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVICE_NAME = orastd)
   )
  )
```

my /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (TCPS, BEQ)
SSL_VERSION = 0
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = FALSE
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5)
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
    (DIRECTORY =/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/AVAYAPDSDB)
    )
  )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE

DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = SUPPORT
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = /tmp/ora
```

Comment: Connect with a username and password.

Comment: if you mean like this : `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin/sqlplus reporter/reporter@AVAYAPDSDB` than that shows same error

Comment: Do you have a `libneq11.so.1` that you can symlink to the same name without the `.1`? Not sure that is actually the problem here. The trace says "Wallet open failed with 28759", and references a file or directory a few lines before; does that exist? Maybe add your `sqlnet.ora` to the question, and if you have wallet files, check the permissions.

Comment: `find / -name "*libneq11.so*"` returns nothing. in a few minutes I would update my question with my .ora files.

Comment: Right, so is your wallet directory there, and accessible, and contains wallet files?

Comment: Well, I have `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin/AVAYAPDSDB/wallet/ ` directory, where I have `cwallet.sso` and `ewallet.p12`. But there was a secific trouble.  I got them from _windows client_. _Instace client for linux_  doesn't provide the `owm` or `prapki` commands to set up new wallet as i found from intermet search.

Comment: I haven't used this for a while; shouldn't the `sqlnet.ora` path include the `wallet` directory?

Comment: I tested with posted path, and with added `/wallet` at the end, and nothing changed. I got an idea that 'system' (dqlplus or smth. else) is looking for wallet in another place. I don't know reaaly how to check if he see the files in specified dir, but there are no errors about the fact that they couldn't be read. I searched in www, and people posted about their issues when trace was telling the exact fact that it can't read the exact file. In my case it is not opening wallet... god... why this nice guys gave only TCPS instead ordinary TCP... ahrrr..

Comment: I placed .sso file and .p12 file on directory above, and got new error: `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Comment: Resolved! Post with resul will write as answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were 2 problems that i was fighting with. First was that the url of wallet was pointing to the directory 1 level above than that where my files were placed, and secondly, I was using short syntax of connection. 
I wsa using this:

```
# /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin/sqlplus /@AVAYAPDSDB
```

And the successfull appeared to be that :

```
# /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin/sqlplus login/password@AVAYAPDSDB
```

So now I would add sqlplus to the PATH and begin to set up php enviroment))

*Hope this all might be usefull for any one. The main advice from me to any one who would be facing similar issues* : **turn on client tracing!!!**

Good luck !

p.s: Some time have Passed, And I realised, that it is important to mention how to trace any proces easily on linux, without any special settings.

For this use command `strace`. Example:

```
strace  -o /tmp/log_of_trace.txt ./configure
```

Instead of ./con... you can call oracle client connection or any other processes that you want to trace. In log you'll get all nesessary information and errors, and all in stacktrace! That is very helpfull!!

A lot of Info for searching where the problem is hiding =)

Luck to all!

Comment: You can self-accept your answer. Thanks for keeping us updated.

Comment: self-accept is possible only after 2 days from creating the issue ^_^  . But still thanks for your help and comments. Glad to know that your researches can be useful to someone else)