# Oracle (instant client) + php (pdo_oci) - ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: php, linux, oracle, pdo

I have a Linux redhat6 server, with apache+nginx servers. To get the data from remote **Oracle** db I compiled pdo_oci.so for my **php 5.3** and it was working perfectly. There were a lot of troubles with configuring **TCPS connection** with **wallet**, but they were solved and were working.

But our server machine was rebooted from **snapshot**, which was made an hour earlier, and this connections fall down. I have checked sqlplus connections, to find out where is the main trouble, and it was not working either. I set up environment variables `$ORACLE_HOME` , `$TNS_ADMIN` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` again, and **sqlplus** connection was **restored**. BUT not the pdo_oci connection. I am searching google for any info, but cannot remember the solution.

The error that I'm getting looks like this:

```
Failed to execute your db connection: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-28759: failure to open file (/usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c:579)
```

Any help and variants are highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you [turned on tracing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284692/oracle-instant-client-ora-28759-failure-to-open-file)?

Comment: Does the file exist in that directory ?

Comment: Yes, but i have no valuable information.  I turned on tracing of odbc connection, due to the fact that oracle uses it, but oracle client is writing there only after establishing the connection. The error that is thown by the php is the only valuable, and the oracle client keep silence.

Comment: @frz3993 I dont remember how to trace where php  driver is trying to call file, and what file is he  calling now. This error is  showing the string in conf file that looks like thiss `/* something to hold errors */
 OCIHandleAlloc(H->env, (dvoid **)&H->err, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, 0, NULL);

 /* handle for the server */
 OCIHandleAlloc(H->env, (dvoid **)&H->server, OCI_HTYPE_SERVER, 0, NULL);

 H->last_err = OCIServerAttach(H->server, H->err, (text*)vars[1].optval,
      strlen(vars[1].optval), OCI_DEFAULT);

 if (H->last_err) {
  oci_drv_error("pdo_oci_handle_factory");
  goto cleanup;
 }
`

Comment: `/usr/local/src/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c` ?

Comment: @frz3993 yes, `oci_drv_error("pdo_oci_handle_factory");` is the line that exception is pointing to

Comment: No, I mean does the file exist there, and with the correct permission ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92233/discussion-between-altenrion-and-frz3993).

Comment: Any help is appreciated